# Girls and boys ordering combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following combinatorics question but I don't know how to approach it:

"10 girls and 4 boys are about to be photographed in a row, how many ordering options are there if between each 2 boys **at least** 1 girl has to stand?"

I know the 4 boys can stand in any order, meaning 4!, but I don't know how to continue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $10!$ ways of arranging the girls. At this point, where can we put the boys, such that no $2$ boys are adjacent?

GGGGGGGGGG

The first boy can be put in $11$ different places ($1$st, last, or between any two girls). The second boy can be put in $10$ different places (we're excluding the place where we put the first boy), the third one in $9$, and the fourth one in $8$.

So in total we have $10! \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ ways.

Comment: I think this was edited wrong, the first boy that can have 11 places was not put in count.

Comment: You're right, I should've been more careful before accepting the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Arranging the girls first is simplest, but here is a solution where we first arrange the boys:

1) We can place the boys in a row in $4!$ ways.

2) Next we can choose places for the girls; since a girl must stand between each pair of boys,

$\;\;\;$we have 7 remaining places to choose for the girls and 4 dividers (the boys),

$\;\;\;$so there are $\binom{11}{4}$ ways to choose the places for the girls.

3) We can place the girls in their places in $10!$ ways.

This gives an answer of $4!\cdot\binom{11}{4}\cdot10!=11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot10!$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting problem. It is easily solved visually. First seat the boys with at least one gap between them. The problem says that between every two boy there has to be at least one girl. So we first sit the boys. _B_B_B_B_. The _ that you see are the gaps. Now the gap can hold more than one girl.Total number of ways in which  we can arrange the boys is $4!$.

Now since we need to have at least one girl between every boy, let us place 5 out of the 10 girls in the gaps. The total number of ways in which we can chose 5 girls out of 10 is $10\choose5$ and we can arrange them in $5!$ ways as we have 5 gaps. Now we have 5 girls remaining. Now these 5 girls can go in any of the possible gaps. Hence we have got another $5!$ way of arranging them.

Hence the total number of ways is
$$4!\cdot{10\choose5}\cdot 5! \cdot 5!  $$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, as you can see someone already answered, how can there be 2 different results?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to know that too. I don't think there is anything wrong with my logic.

Comment: Of the five gaps you have identified, only the three gaps that lie between two boys must be filled with a girl.  Also, once you count the number of ways of filling the five spaces you have identified with ten objects, there are $10!$ permutations of the girls.